# Angular Material + Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova, material-design

im trying to use Material Design by google(Angular Material) to develop a app using phonegap (so i pretend it to work in iOS or other os)

why this code is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.6.1/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hammerjs/2.0.4/hammer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.6 used here -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.6.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<md-button>
  Button
</md-button>
<md-button href="http://google.com" class="md-button-colored">
  I'm a link
</md-button>
<md-button ng-disabled="true" class="md-colored">
  I'm a disabled button
</md-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

[THE PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/mfWix0esDkBgjBBgYqWC?p=preview)

for both, cellphone / computer, it just show like the plkr = plain text =|

what im doing wrong since its a ctrl c + ctrl v from the tutorial:

Any solution or fix?

nobody worked with phonegap + angular material yet?

Comment: Hi, this is not the answer, did you test angular material on the real device? if yes how is the speed?

Answer (score 1):

solution:

1) Moving everything src/import to `<HEAD>`

and

2) I forgot to add:

```
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngMaterial' ]);
</script>
```

and than:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" layout="vertical">
</div>
```

everything working now ;)

Comment: You should move your scripts down just before your </body> tag. If you put it in the head, you load the scripts before your HTML. It's just good practice to move your scripts down so they load after the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use network sources to load Angular-Material, load the files inside the project.

You can get it on Bower or Npm.

Also you can use a seed:
 https://github.com/marioaleogolsat/cordova-angular-angularMaterial-seed

Answer (score 0):

Define Angular Material Dependencies **BEFORE** creating your angular module :

```
  <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.6.1/angular-material.min.css">

        <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hammerjs/2.0.4/hammer.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.6 used here -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.6.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngMaterial' ]);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">


        <div layout="vertical">

    <md-button>
      Button
    </md-button>
    <md-button href="http://google.com" class="md-button-colored">
      I'm a link
    </md-button>
    <md-button ng-disabled="true" class="md-colored">
      I'm a disabled button
    </md-button>
    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```